# Eliminate characters in AS400

Tags: sql, select, insert, ibm-midrange, datastage

i found a problem in my data. 
I used datastage tool and the source from aqua studio.

Example, i have 4 field in my table. and my data like this :

TABLE : TEST_1

`CSHADD1                        SIGN01     SHADD2        SIGN02 ---------------------------------------------------------------
JL TERATAI Gg BUANA TANJUNG     ||         RT04 RW03     ||`

i just do select query :

```
insert into TEST_2 
select
CSHADD1 AS ADDRESS1,
SHADD2 AS ADDRESS2
from TEST_1
```

But the result in TEST_2 :

```
ADDRESS1                                   ADDRESS2
--------------------------------------------------
JL TERATAI Gg BUANA TANJUNG RT04 RW03      RT04 RW03
```

values in column ADDRESS2 entered into column ADDRESS1, it shouldn't be there.
what should I do?

Comment: PLease rechekc of your original data really doesn't contain the whole "JL TERATAI Gg BUANA TANJUNG RT04 RW03" String. Your SQL statement seems not to be producing this error... Are there maybe any other possible problem sources around?

Comment: I already check whole data. but the data still show that. are the problem is used the datastage or else?

Comment: To rule out datastage, stop using it. If you are able, log directly into your system with a 5250 session or an iNavigator SQL window. What version of the OS is the server using? What driver & version are you using?

Comment: Is there a trigger on the TEST_2 table which could be updating ADDRESS1?

Comment: You show apparent values from two tables. How are those values retrieved from the tables? How are the values displayed so that you can copy them here? The value for `ADDRESS1` looks similar to a particular "parameter mismatch" problem, though that seems unlikely. The more we know, the better we can guess.